# List all cells in an array that contain a word?

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet containging information about internet connections between 2 points. Column B provides a small description of the connection E.g. 1Gb Dublin to London. I want to create a new sheet where I can type in a location, Dublin for example, and list all the cells with the descriptions that contain the word Dublin.

I am sure this is easy enough although I can't find a solution. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want the **address** of the cells or the **contents** of the cells or both??

Comment: The Contents Of the cells

Answer (score 0):

Use an AutoFilter with the **Contains...** option.  You can copy the visible cells and paste them to the new sheet.  For a reference, see:  [Contextures Article](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html)

Comment: that isn't really usefull in this situation. I am  going to create a drop down list with all the locations then display all the connections from that location and then apply some formulas to the other information. It is just the formula to list all the cells that contain the word I am searching for that I need.

Comment: Would a **VBA** macro-based solution be acceptable??

Comment: I Don't know how to use macros :/ Surely it can be done, the COUNTIF function can count how many times a word appears in an array so I would imagine listing them instances should be straight forward.

Comment: I can find the first instance in the array using the formula =INDEX('Report Summary'!B4:B388, MATCH("*"&B1&"*",'Report Summary'!B4:B388,0))

Comment: the problem is listing the rest of them

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following macro in the worksheet code area of the sheet you want the data to be placed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim B As Range, sb As Range, r As Range, Lookit As Range, I As Long
    Set sb = Range("B1")
    Set B = Range("B:B")
    Set Lookit = Sheets("Report Summary").Range("B4:B388")
    If Intersect(Target, sb) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    v = sb.Text
    B.Clear
    sb.Value = v
    I = 2
    For Each r In Lookit
        vv = r.Value
        If InStr(vv, v) > 0 Then
            Cells(I, "B").Value = vv
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then type a value in cell **B1**

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!